# The instance member 'uid' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-streambuilder

Here I have a StreamBuilder with a custom ListView widget.

```
StreamBuilder<Location>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              else {
                return ListViewWidget(
                  locations: locationList,                     
                );
              }
            },
        stream: getLocations,
     ),
```

What I want to do is add the new item to the list and show it in the ListView widget.
The problem is, that I can not use the uid and the locationList list because I got this error message:

> The instance member 'uid' can't be accessed in an initializer

.

```
   Stream<Location> getLocations = (() async* {
        await for (var snapshot in FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('loggedin')
            .doc(uid)
            .collection('locations')
            .snapshots()) {
          for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
            Location location = Location(
                id: doc['id'],
                name: doc['name'],
                description: doc['description'],
             );
            locationList.add(location);    
            yield location;
          }
        }
      })();
```

How could I update the list and show it on a ListView with StreamBuilder?

Comment: could you please include full code so we can regenerate the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the way you declared the `getLocation` stream.
It should be declared like a function, this way:

```dart
Stream<Location> getLocations() async* {
  // your content here
}
```

This might correct your error.

But I strongly recommend you reading this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart

Which provides a sample of code to get realtime updates from a Firestore collection.